# edge detection opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

it is my code and I'm trying to edge detection using the sobel method. But I'm getting neither error nor image.If I have a mistake, can you explain where it is?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread("lena.jpg")
img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
m,n=img.shape


kernelx=np.array([[-1, -2, -1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 1]])
kernely=np.array([[-1, 0, 1], [-2, 0, 2], [-1, 0, 1]])


gx=np.zeros((m,n), dtype=np.int32)
gy=np.zeros((m,n), dtype=np.int32)


for x in range(1,m-1):
    for y in range(1,n-1):
        for a in range(3):
            for b in range(3):
                xn = x + a - 1
                yn = y + b - 1
                gx=gx+(kernelx[a][b]*img[xn][yn])
                gy=gy+(kernely[a][b]*img[xn][yn])






        final_image=np.sqrt(pow(gx,2.0)+pow(gy,2.0))



cv2.imshow("a",final_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Are you able to write a program using `imshow` that displays *any* image (without trying to do edge detection on top)?

Comment: ı did not understand

Comment: Can you write a working program that loads an image and displays it?

Comment: yes ı can use cv2

Comment: img=cv2.imread("lena.jpg")

cv2.imshow("img",img)

Comment: where is the problem,I am about to go crazy

Comment: Okay so what happens when you use `cv2.imshow("img", final_image)` instead of `cv2.imshow("img", img)`?

Comment: nothing,not responding

Comment: What do you get when you add `print(x, y, a, b)` before `xn = x + a - 1`?

Comment: it print =1 x (0,1,2) (0,1,2).for example 1 301 0 1

Comment: So you get one line of output and that's it?

Comment: there is more than one but ı cant write them.x is increasing

Comment: You seem like a knowledgeable person and I was so embarrassed by this situation.sorry about that :(

Comment: No need to apologize. It seems your program just needs more time to finish all the calculations.

Comment: I want to see the results of these codes results after click to run button.If the program takes time to run, this means there is an error in the code, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your code.
Try to use cv2.filter2D() instead of your for loop.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r"lena.jpg")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
m, n = img.shape

kernelx = np.array([[-1, -2, -1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 1]])
kernely = np.array([[-1, 0, 1], [-2, 0, 2], [-1, 0, 1]])

img_x = cv2.filter2D(img, ddepth=cv2.CV_8U, kernel=kernelx)
img_y = cv2.filter2D(img, ddepth=cv2.CV_8U, kernel=kernely)

final_image = np.sqrt(pow(img_x, 2.0) + pow(img_y, 2.0))

cv2.imshow("a", final_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

if you want to do it with a for loop, the right way of doing it is:
I add a tqdm progress bar for you ;)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

img = cv2.imread(r"lena.jpg")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
m, n = img.shape

kernelx = np.array([[-1, -2, -1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 1]])
kernely = np.array([[-1, 0, 1], [-2, 0, 2], [-1, 0, 1]])

out_im = np.zeros((m-2, n-2))
g_x = np.zeros((m-2, n-2))
g_y = np.zeros((m-2, n-2))
for m_i in tqdm(range(m-2)):
    for n_i in range(n-2):
        im_patch = img[m_i:m_i+3, n_i:n_i+3]
        g_x[m_i, n_i] = sum([i * k for i, k in zip(im_patch.flatten(), kernelx.flatten())])
        g_y[m_i, n_i] = sum([i * k for i, k in zip(im_patch.flatten(), kernely.flatten())])

out_im = np.sqrt(g_x ** 2 + g_y ** 2)

out_im = np.uint8(out_im/out_im.max() * 255)

cv2.imshow("", out_im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

#### Note:

You may need to normalize the image before display.

Comment: Actually,ı know this method but ı want to write like my code but ı dont know how it is

Comment: The for loop does not do convolution or 2d filtering as it should do.

Comment: Try to read the definition of convolution

Comment: But why does the program not respond anymore?

Comment: your code is working.but I can't say the same for mine

Comment: I think it runs, it just takes a lot of time to run so you think it is stuck. Try to add prints in the for loop, you will see it running.  Furthermore, you have an error in your calculation. I add above a new code *with* for loop for you :)

Comment: it's clear.Can't we do this without using modules?

Comment: Of course, you can (if I understood your question :)). I modified the code above, tell me if it satisfies you.

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you for your help so far.ı want to detect edges use sobel method.actually**,take every 3x3 pixels of 1d image, multiply it with kernelx and write the total to a zeros image (name as gx)** .This is not a homework, it's just a work I do to improve myself.

Comment: @MustafaAyanoğlu I modified the code above. Tell me if it satisfy you.

Comment: its clear and its satisfy me but Can you try without using the flatten function.This request is just out of curiosity